# FlannBasedMatcher gives different results when run on different computers

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm using FlannBasedMatcher for image registration, and every computer I run on seems to give different results. Here are the paramters:

```
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 5
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 1)
search_params = dict(checks=100)  
self.matcher = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params,search_params)
```

Is it due to the change in number of cores in the CPU? How do I make the results consistent across all computers?

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405686/flannbasedmatcher-returning-different-results FLANN might use randomized trees -> isn't deterministic so results might differ. Bruteforce matcher should definitely give deterministic results.

Comment: Is there anyway I can optimize the speed of BFmatcher? Speed is the only liability holding me back.

Comment: no, that's what FLANN is for, but it might be non-deterministic... So it'll depend on which is more important for you: Speed or determinism.